# MobileFirst client properties does not seems to change

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In my project even if i change my server host using build settings and deploy target , the client properties does not change in the `wlClient.properties` file , however the context path changes to new one, the server host url is pointing to my local host now ,also one thing i have noted that `wlBuildId` this property is missing in the file

My version is :`7.1.0.00.20150901-2103`

What i have done :
Changed the server url in `Right click > Run As > Build setting and Deploy target` and rebuild the project  even after rebuilding the `wlClient.properties` file the `wlServerHost` property doesn't change

Attached the settings screen along with this

[image]

Comment: Why not be more specific? Provide an actual example, mention your MobileFirst version,.. .

Comment: @IdanAdar i have made the question specific along with the screenshot

Comment: Did you try adding the port value?

Comment: yes tried that too still the same  @IdanAdar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally tracked down the problem , actually it was a bug in the build i have installed.

I installed the mobile first plugin from eclipse market which was of version `7.1.0.00.2015` which has the bug, then i removed the plugin and downloaded the package from IBM Mobile firsts website which was of build version `7.1.0.00.2016` which has the fix for this bug and it is rectified now.

The point to note is that the package in the eclipse's market has to be changed to the new build in which the issue is fixed.

Thank you